# Fluent Validation never works with any condition MVC 5

Tags: c#, fluent, fluentvalidation

I am using  fluent validation in my Project but it never works with any condition . In simple case without any condition it works fine . But When I use dependentRule or  when condtion, it never worked. This is really frustrating I have tried more than 100 times after going through Fluent document but none worked for me . Please any one have idea why this when condition is not firing and there is any way to view the values.

```
public class Employee
  {
    public string Qualification { get; set; }
    public bool IsRebadged { get; set; }

  }
public class EmployeePersonalDetailsValidator : AbstractValidator<Employee>
{
    public EmployeePersonalDetailsValidator()
    {

        Qualification();
    }
    public void Qualification()
    {
        RuleFor(dto => dto.Qualification)
         .NotEmpty()
         .When(d => d.IsRebadged == true)
         .WithMessage("Please get your Qualification updated");
    }




 <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                    <label>Qualification</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Qualification, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })                    
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Qualification, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                </div>
```

FilterConfig.cs

```
 public class FilterConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure();
        }
    }
```

I Have configured the same in Global.asax  but not working
Global.asax

```
 protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;
            FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure();

        }
```

Comment: Is this about asp.net, console application, winforms?

Comment: @Marco does it matter?

Comment: OP can you demonstrate how you're using the validator? And include the definition of `Employee`?

Comment: John, I think so, yes. In Asp.net core, you just hook it up in Startup.cs and it works. In console applications you'd have to manually call `validator.validate(foo)`, or not?

Comment: @Marco Ah yes, I forgot about that.

Comment: And that's why I'm asking. Could be that  op, is either not hooking it up into the pipeline in Asp.Net Core, or he just is not calling `.validate()`. Given the informtion in his question, both possibilities are valid to me

Comment: i am using this in MVC 5

Comment: Would you please show us, how you configured FluentValidation in your `Application_Start()` method?

Comment: protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;
            FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure();

        }